# I edited the brand.png picture, but the old one still shows up in the bakery template

Tags: webmatrix

I'm a beginner at webprogramming and am just starting to fool around with the Bakery template in Microsofts Webmatrix. I'm trying to change the logo shown in the layout and looking in the Images folder for the template, there is only 2 pictures and one of them is called brand.png. I used Paint to edit it and save it again. But whenever I run the website from Webmatrix, it shows the old logo that doesn't exist anymore. Is the IIS (or whatever is running as default) doing some caching or what is going on? And how do I fix this?

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache?

Answer (score 1):

Try F5 or CTRL+F5 to clear cache.

Answer (score 0):

line 103 of the site.css file,

```
background: transparent url(../Images/brand.png) no-repeat;
```

delete the following text brand.png, then f5 to clear browser cache